# Cross database query not returning wanted result

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, dblink

I'm trying to get data from another database "Finantial" but the result its returning is not the same as the result I get in the other database with the same code minus the dblinks

Here is the code I'm  having issues with:

```sql
select trans.accountid ,sum(trans.amount)as montantpaye,loan.amount-sum(trans.amount) as montantrestant,loan.duration-count(trans.transid) as moisrestant
from (SELECT * FROM dblink('user=postgres password=password dbname=finantial', 'select amount,accountid,duration from loan')
    AS loan(amount int,accountid int,duration int)) as loan,
    (SELECT * FROM dblink('user=postgres password=password dbname=finantial', 'select accountid from account')
    AS account(accountid int)) as account,
    (SELECT * FROM dblink('user=postgres password=password dbname=finantial', 'select amount,accountid,ksymbol,transid from trans')
    AS trans(accountid int,amount int,ksymbol varchar,transid int)) as trans
 where trans.ksymbol='UVER' and
        account.accountid=loan.accountid and
        trans.accountid=account.accountid
group by (trans.accountid,loan.amount,loan.duration)
```

and here's what i get

[image]

whereas when I query this data in the database "finantial" with this code :

```sql
select trans.accountid, sum(trans.amount)as montant_paye,loan.amount-sum(trans.amount) as montant_restant,loan.duration-count(trans.transid) as moisrestant
from loan, account,trans
 where account.accountid=loan.accountid and ksymbol='UVER' and trans.accountid=account.accountid
group by (trans.accountid,loan.amount,loan.duration)
```

I get this result :

[image]

I would appreciate it if you could tell me what I need to fix in my code.

Comment: well, results are unsorted sets. Did you compare all rows or just the first 6? Try `1st Selet except 2nd Select`

Comment: @dnoeth yes the 1st code returned 33 rows whereas the 2nd code returned 682 rows ,and I don't understand how to use the select except..

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use `JOIN`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Would this change the result? No

Comment: The EXCEPT is a set operator like UNION and can be used to check if two queries return exactly the same result. But in your case the number of rows already differs while the Selects are equivalent, strange.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried with join, it didn't change anything

Comment: @dnoeth do you have any idea what the problem might be ? I really need this to work

Comment: No, wait for the PG guys

Comment: First I would add an `ORDER BY accountid` so you can see where the break is between the two sets. Second why not put the entire query(as shown for your local example) in the `dblink()`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver putting the entire query in one `dblink()` fixed the problem, thank you a lot !

Comment: You don't say what Postgres version you are on or what control you have over the database, but you might consider [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html). It is a somewhat easier way to access remote Postgres databases.

Comment: Alright I will, thanks again.